# How to add loader in my html to wait for data fetching

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a part of my html that triggers data fetching when a button is being clicked, sometimes it takes time for the data to come back and I want to lock the screen with loader until the data is retrieved, how can I do that?

this is the current code:

```
 <button *ngFor="#ele of myListOfButtons" md-button (click)="bringDataToDisplay(ele.id)"> 
{{ele.name}}
  </button>
```

So I want a loader when there is a click on `bringDataToDisplay` and until the data is back (its basically an api call to bring the data so its async, using Observables).

thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isLoading:boolean = false;

bringDataToDisplay(id) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.http.get(...).subscribe(response => {
    ... process response
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

```
<loader *ngIf="isLoading"></loader>
<div *ngIf="!isLoading">
  normal content
</div>
```

Comment: that works great, accept how do I add an actual loader that blocking the  screen so no one could click on anything while its loading?

Comment: add a div position absolute 0,0, size 100vh, 100vw, transparent, z-index 1000

Answer (score 0):

Please add this *Jquery* above the `<html>`

```
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
    $('#loader-wrapper').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
    $('#loader').delay(500).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
})
```

And the following in side it:

```
<div id="loader-wrapper" class="">
    <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*preloader*/
#loader-wrapper{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #222;
}
#loader{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    /*border: #3498db solid 3px;*/
    z-index: 1500;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: transparent solid 3px;
    border-top-color: #3498db;
    animation: spin 2.5s linear infinite;
}
#loader:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    /*border: #e74c3c solid 3px;*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: transparent solid 3px;
    border-top-color: #ff034b;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#loader:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    /*border: #f9c922 solid 3px;*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: transparent solid 3px;
    border-top-color: #eee;
    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Here's a link to another way of doing this https://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL

I hope it's useful.